# Setting up low-latency client/server example in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I have a simple ECHO server and client written using Netty. The server and client are on the same machine. I was expecting mean latency of the order of a couple of milliseconds, however, regardless of what I try I can never bring the latency down to sub-millisecond durations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Even when using System.nanoTime I see the latency around 25-30ms.

EchoClient

```
import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.*;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ExecutionHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class EchoClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println(String.format("usage: %s <num-msgs>", EchoClient.class.getCanonicalName()));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        final long NUM_MSGS = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        final EchoClientHandler echoClientHandler = new EchoClientHandler();

        final ExecutionHandler e =
                new ExecutionHandler(new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(4, 128 * 1024L, 128 * 1024L));
        ChannelFactory factory =
                new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                                                  Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

        ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(factory);
        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
            @Override
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
                return Channels.pipeline(new TestPayloadEncoder(),
                                         new TestPayloadDecoder(),
                                         e,
                                         echoClientHandler);
            }
        });
        bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("keepAlive", false);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", false);
        bootstrap.setOption("sendBufferSize", 128 * 1024L);
        bootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSize", 128 * 1024L);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MSGS; i++) {
            final InetSocketAddress serverAddr =
                    new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080);

            bootstrap.connect(serverAddr).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture f) throws Exception {
                    if (f.isSuccess()) {
                        f.getChannel().write(new TestPayload());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        while (echoClientHandler.numMsgs.get() < NUM_MSGS);

        System.out.println(echoClientHandler.numMsgs);
        System.out.println(echoClientHandler.aggTime);
        System.out.println(String.format("mean transfer time: %.2fms",
                                         ((float) echoClientHandler.aggTime.get()) /
                                         echoClientHandler.numMsgs.get()));
        System.out.flush();

        e.releaseExternalResources();
        factory.releaseExternalResources();
    }

}
```

EchoClientHandler

```
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ExceptionEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class EchoClientHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    public final AtomicLong numMsgs = new AtomicLong(0);
    public final AtomicLong aggTime = new AtomicLong(0);

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        long recvTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        TestPayload m = (TestPayload) e.getMessage();
        aggTime.addAndGet(recvTime - m.getTime());
        numMsgs.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) throws Exception {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        e.getChannel().close();
    }

}
```

EchoServer

```
import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ExecutionHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChannelFactory factory =
                new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4),
                                                  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(32),
                                                  32);

        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);
        final ExecutionHandler e =
                new ExecutionHandler(new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(4, 128 * 1024L, 128 * 1024L));
        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
            @Override
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
                return Channels.pipeline(e, new EchoServerHandler());
            }
        });
        bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddr", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("keepAlive", false);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.reuseAddr", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.soLinger", 0);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", false);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.sendBufferSize", 128 * 1024L);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.receiveBufferSize", 128 * 1024L);
        bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080));
    }

}
```

EchoServerHandler

```
import org.jboss.netty.channel.*;

public class EchoServerHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        e.getChannel().write(e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) throws Exception {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        e.getChannel().close();
    }

}
```

TestPayload

```
import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class TestPayload {

    private static final int PREAMBLE_LEN = (Long.SIZE + Integer.SIZE) / 8;

    private static final Random RNG;
    static {
        RNG = new Random();
        RNG.setSeed(new Date().getTime());
    }

    private final int    paddingLen;
    private final byte[] padding;
    private final long   time;

    public TestPayload() {
        this(65536);
    }

    public TestPayload(int sizeInBytes) {
        this.paddingLen = sizeInBytes;
        this.padding = new byte[this.paddingLen];
        RNG.nextBytes(this.padding);
        this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private TestPayload(long time, int paddingLen, byte[] padding) {
        this.paddingLen = paddingLen;
        this.padding = padding;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }

    public void writeTo(ChannelBuffer buf) {
        buf.writeLong(this.time);
        buf.writeInt(this.paddingLen);
        buf.writeBytes(this.padding);
    }

    public static TestPayload readFrom(ChannelBuffer buf) {
        if (buf.readableBytes() < PREAMBLE_LEN) {
            return null;
        }

        buf.markReaderIndex();

        long time = buf.readLong();
        int paddingLen = buf.readInt();

        if (buf.readableBytes() < paddingLen) {
            buf.resetReaderIndex();
            return null;
        }

        byte[] padding = new byte[paddingLen];
        buf.readBytes(padding);

        return new TestPayload(time, paddingLen, padding);
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return PREAMBLE_LEN + this.paddingLen;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to measure sub-millis then use System.nanoTime() which is a timer. System.currentTimeMillis() is a "wall clock

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your client and your server in different JVMs?  If so, measuring time across JVM boundaries is not as straight forward as you would think.  For example using System.nanoTime() is not necessarily going to work according to the [oracle java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()):

> The values returned by this method become meaningful only when the difference between two such values, obtained within the same instance of a Java virtual machine, is computed.

Assuming you can find a reliable way to measure time across JVMs and if your goal is to isolate how long it takes a Netty client to send to a Netty server then simplify your use case to isolate this as much as possible. For example, in the above code you are counting the time to send/receive an array of 65536 bytes.  Remove this from the timing experiment to help isolate where the bottlenecks are.

How many runs are you collecting timing from?  Are you excluding initialization time of Netty itself (running a few messages between client/server before taking timing)?

Also how does adjusting your configuration impact performance? There are plenty of knobs to tweak (thread pool size, send/receive buff size, etc...).

What version of Netty are you using, and is there an option to force a flush after you write?

I don't see the code for `EchoClient`. It looks like you copy/pasted the code for `EchoClientHandler` where `EchoClient`'s code should be.

Comment: Yes, the client and server are in different JVMs. I'm trying to measure the time elapsed from the time my send started to the time the receive completed. It is possible that this timer could capture a bit more than what I want to measure exactly, but for the most part I believe it should be OK.

Comment: I don't know what to configure to get sub-millisecond latencies. Actually anything below 4-6ms would be great if I can achieve that.

Comment: You don't know it is OK until you experiment.  Can you post numbers with your test case complexity reduced, and with these number add some justification as to how you are doing timing cross JVM?  Also you will have to experiment with the different options you set.  For example what are the advantages/disadvantages to modifying the `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` parameters?  Do you need as many threads as you are using?

Comment: Also do you need to be establishing a new connection for each message that you send?  Now that your `EchoClient` code is posted I see you are doing a `bootstrap.connect(...)` in a loop for each message.  Can you just connect 1 time and re-use this connection?  You also have a busy loop waiting for responses to be received.  Can you change this approach to a non-busy loop (i.e. initialize `numMsgs` to the anticipated messages and do a .countDown() for each message received. then you can do a `numMsgs.await(...)` (or some other form of await) to avoid the busy-loop)).

Comment: Are you sure your cleanup is catching everything for the `EchoClient`?  For example are you closing each socket and cleaning up any Executor/thread groups?  On the server side I don't see any clean up (unless an exception is thrown then that socket is closed).  Also I don't see code for `TestPayloadEncoder` or `TestPayloadDecoder`.

Comment: the wait/notify scheme be slower (have seen it in one of the experiments) than the busy loop scheme.

Comment: if I can reuse the connection, the speed does drop; however, the application I have in mind cannot use persistent connections!